# Kustomize: how to apply the same patch in multiple overlays without LoadRestrictionsNone

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a kustomize layout something like this:

```
├──release
│  ├──VariantA
│  │  └──kustomization.yaml
│  │     cluster_a.yaml
|  └──VariantB
│     └──kustomization.yaml
│        cluster_b.yaml
└──test
   ├──TestVariantA
   │  └──kustomization.yaml; resources=[VariantA]
   │     common_cluster_patch.yaml
   └──TestVariantB
      └──kustomization.yaml; resources=[VariantB]
         common_cluster_patch.yaml
```

My issue is the duplication of `common_cluster_patch.yaml`. It is a common patch which I need to apply to the the different base cluster objects. I would prefer not to have to maintain identical copies of it for each test variant.

The 2 unsuccessful solutions I tried are:

**A common patch resource**

```
├──release
│  ├──VariantA
│  │  └──kustomization.yaml
│  │     cluster_a.yaml
|  └──VariantB
│     └──kustomization.yaml
│        cluster_b.yaml
└──test
   ├──TestVariantA
   │  └──kustomization.yaml; resources=[VariantA, TestPatch]
   ├──TestVariantB
   │  └──kustomization.yaml; resources=[VariantB, TestPatch]
   └──TestPatch
      └──kustomization.yaml
         common_cluster_patch.yaml
```

This fails with `no matches for Id Cluster...`, presumably because TestPatch is trying to patch an object it doesn't contain.

**A common patch directory**

```
├──release
│  ├──VariantA
│  │  └──kustomization.yaml
│  │     cluster_a.yaml
|  └──VariantB
│     └──kustomization.yaml
│        cluster_b.yaml
└──test
   ├──TestVariantA
   │  └──kustomization.yaml; resources=[VariantA]; patches=[../TestPatch/common_cluster_patch.yaml]
   ├──TestVariantB
   │  └──kustomization.yaml; resources=[VariantB]; patches=[../TestPatch/common_cluster_patch.yaml]
   └──TestPatch
      └──common_cluster_patch.yaml
```

This fails with: `'/path/to/test/TestPatch/common_cluster_patch.yaml' is not in or below '/path/to/test/TestVariantA'`.

I can work round this and successfully generate my templates with `kustomize build --load-restrictor LoadRestrictionsNone`, but this comes with dire warnings and portents. I am hoping that there is some better way of organising my resources which doesn't require either workarounds or duplication.

Comment: Have you considered Kustomize Components?

Comment: https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/config_management/components/

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the solution! I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to criztovyl for this answer! The solution is [kustomize components](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/config_management/components/). Components are currently only defined in `kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1` and the [reference documentation](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/components/) is a stub, but they are included in current release versions of kustomize.

My solution now looks like:

```
├──release
│  ├──VariantA
│  │  └──kustomization.yaml
│  │     cluster_a.yaml
|  └──VariantB
│     └──kustomization.yaml
│        cluster_b.yaml
└──test
   ├──TestVariantA
   │  └──kustomization.yaml; resources=[VariantA]; components=[../TestCommon]
   ├──TestVariantB
   │  └──kustomization.yaml; resources=[VariantB]; components=[../TestCommon]
   └──TestCommon
      └──kustomization.yaml; patches=[common_cluster_patch.yaml]
         common_cluster_patch.yaml
```

where `test/TestCommon/kustomization.yaml` has the header:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
```

The crucial difference between a component and a resource is that a component is applied after other processing. This means it can patch an object in the resource which included it.